# Extracting data from a very large dataset using matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, extract

http://tinypic.com/r/2dt5ge1/5 
this is the link of screen shot of data which i want to extract.Data contains total 5,00,000 records/rows, what i want to do is, extract only those rows which has 19 at a particular position.

As you can see in the 9th and 19th row, after two 350 in the middle, there is 19. So i want to extract these rows only.Please help.
Also how many columns should i make while importing and in which format(text or numeric).

Comment: 5 million rows no longer counts as a particularly big data set.

Comment: so 19 is not a separate number, its a part of string, correct?

Comment: Yes.
but i can make it a separate number by making columns.

Answer (score 0):

The data set is not really large, I would import everything and filter then. Using a numeric format, your data is <500MB which should be no Problem.

Start here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/import_export/import-numeric-data-from-a-text-file.html

To filter your data quick, use logical indexing e.g. `data(data(:,4)==19,:)` which would select every row where the 4-th column is 19.